# How to access model-specific constant in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I'd like to generate some dynamic routes based on a constant that's stored in one of my models, but I'm getting an error indicating that I don't have access to that constant from the router.

Here's my router snippet:

```
MyShowroom::CATEGORIES.each do |category|
    match "#{category}", :controller => :my_showrooms, :action => :index, :type => category, :as => category
end
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> NameError: uninitialized constant MyShowroom::CATEGORIES

So basically, I just need to know the proper way to access a model constant in routes.rb

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you show the model also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file called `constants.rb` inside the `app/config/initializers/` directory. And then you are done to use them anywhere.Then put the module, class or any constants, inside `constants` that you want to use any places inside your app.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Arup. FYI, I'm actually going to provide my own answer just so people can see entirely how I implemented this, but yours was definitely the answer I needed, so I marked yours as the accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Arup gave me the answer I needed to figure out how to implement this (thanks Arup!), but I just wanted to give my own answer to show how this was *fully* implemented to hopefully help others out.

I left my enum constant defined in my model, because I want to keep things very logically organized (i.e. the enum is directly related to the model so that's where it belongs). To make the constant available across the application, I created a `constants.rb` file in `app/config/initializers` and then I created a new constant in that file that simply pointed to the constant I already had defined in my model - effectively making the constant that's defined within my model available across the application.

Here's the full implementation:

#### my_showroom.rb (Model)

```
CATEGORIES = {
  1 => 'Opinions Please',
  2 => 'Budget Minded',
  3 => 'Getting Started',
  4 => 'Ever Evolving',
  5 => 'Done for Now',
  6 => 'All Out Assault',
  7 => 'Home Theater',
  8 => 'Secondary Rigs'
}
```

#### constants.rb

```
MY_SHOWROOM_CATEGORIES = MyShowroom::CATEGORIES
```

#### routes.rb

```
MY_SHOWROOM_CATEGORIES.each do |key, value|
  action_name = value.tr(' ', '_').downcase
  get "my_showrooms/#{action_name}", to: "my_showrooms##{action_name}"
end
```

#### Generated Routes

[image: Generated Routes]